# Is there a test (in R) for predicting the proportion of "successes" to "failures"?

Tags: logistic, binomial-distribution, proportion

As I understand it, binomial logistic regression is good for predicting the probability of a "1" outcome from a discrete binomial distribution. What if instead, one wanted to predict the proportion of 1's to 0's (the proportion of sick to healthy, or animals with full stomachs to empty stomachs, etc...). I thought the prop.test in R was a good solution, but it doesn't seem built for scenarios where the data consists of multiple explanatory variables and/or factors with multiple levels.

My data could look something like this (with many more replicates and site values [a to z]):

[image]

Comment: am I missing something? Can you just use `1-stomatch_empty` as your response variable?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what 1-stomach_empty is either. Just the value "1" minus what ever my response variable stomach_empty value takes? The variable stomach_empty  is a "yes/no" variable and each row is an individual (fish lets say) caught for analysis. I'd like to know if I could perhaps use logistic regression to predict the proportion of fish with empty stomachs as the variables take on different values.

Comment: Here's a good explanation: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/when-to-use-logistic-regression-for-percentages-and-counts/   ...I just don't know how to do it yet. Maybe I need to re-organize my data to a different form? Maybe percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logistic regression does both: the predicted probabilities of success are the same as the predicted proportion of individuals with that set of covariates who would be a "success".

Eg, suppose you fit the logistic model and you find that an individual with (salinity = 25, temp = 15, site = a) has a predicted probability of Stomach Empty = 1 of 85%. This is the same as if you took a large sample of individuals who all had (salinity = 25, temp = 15, site = a) then the predicted proportion of those individuals who are Stomach Empty = 1 is 85%.

If further, you want to predict the overall proportion for a dataset consisting of a variety of different individuals, then you'll have to do some arithmetic to add them up. But that should be straightforward.